# Thread Pool and it thread provide

Tags: c#, threadpool

My code is

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    { 
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(y => 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }); 
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

When I start program and look at the sos.dll I can see that every time thread pool provide me 4-5 threads. Hereupon occurs delay because pool don't give more threads.
Why is this happening?

Comment: How many cores has your machine got?

Comment: Unless you have 8 or more cores, 4 - 5 is probably pretty good without thrashing? Also, did you read the [documentaion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ThreadPool Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> There is one thread pool per process. Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the default size of the thread pool for a process depends on several factors, such as the size of the virtual address space. A process can call the GetMaxThreads method to determine the number of threads. **The number of threads in the thread pool can be changed by using the SetMaxThreads method.** Each thread uses the default stack size and runs at the default priority.

As an additional note, depending on system resources (like CPU cores, RAM, etc.), more threads may not make your application run faster.